# Batch Rename Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

A pretty basic question. I'm a novice with batch scripts, so forgive me if this is remedial.

I regularly have to rename hundreds of files. There's no patterns here, simple one-for-one renaming. And so I've been creating batch scripts consisting of hundreds of lines of rename commands like these:

```
REN STWP01_00103033* 2009-07-15_BCBSRI-00170952*
REN BCBSRI-00003876* 2011-07-15_BCBSRI-00003876*
```

It's a pain to reformat every entry to include the rename command at the beginning of the line and the wildcards after each filename [REN oldname* newname*]. Is there a way to specify those at the beginning of a code block and then just paste in a list of the old/new file names? something like:

```
REN 
{
STWP01_00103033 2009-07-15_BCBSRI-00170952
BCBSRI-00003876 2011-07-15_BCBSRI-00003876
}
```

This way I can re-use the batch file and simply paste the strings of old/new names into the body and run it.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, there's variables and whatnot you can define.

Comment: You can use a `FOR /F` command to read a file and use the two values as variables for your rename.

Answer (score 0):

This script will read `ren` commands from a file called `rename.ini`.

To rename all files beginning with `file1` to `file2`, you would use

```
file1 file2
```

## Script:

```
@echo off
if not exist rename.ini (echo [Batch renaming utility]>rename.ini&echo Edit 'rename.ini' to start&goto exit)
for /F "eol=[ tokens=1-2" %%A in (rename.ini) do (ren %%A* %%B* 1>nul)
echo Job complete!
:exit
pause
exit
```

## Rename.ini script

```
[Batch renaming utility]

    STWP01_00103033 2009-07-15_BCBSRI-00170952
    BCBSRI-00003876 2011-07-15_BCBSRI-00003876
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I look forward to testing this out!